# Nested For Loops for Array Item Removal

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, logic, nested-loops

This is probably a noobish question but, i have been working on this project and couldn't get it to work. I got frustrated and experimented around and got it to work somehow. The change i made was i added a -1 to numOfItem.

I would really appreciate if someone could explain to me why this worked. My head is not really reading the code properly i believe. I am under the impression that if i am removing an item on the last index, it should throw an error.

```
for (int j = i; j < numOfItem - 1; j++)
```

This code belongs to a nested for loop in this method:

```
//Removes only a single instance of the specified item.
//If the item doesnt exist in the bag, it returns false
public boolean remove(Object item) {
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfItem; i++) {
        if (stuff[i].equals(item)) {
            for (int j = i; j < numOfItem - 1; j++) 
               stuff[j] = stuff[j + 1];
            stuff[numOfItem - 1] = null;
            numOfItem--;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;   
}
```

numOfItem is set to 0, when an object bag is initialized, as to signify there are 0 items in the bag, however the bag is given a max capacity (user input) when initialized. If any more info is needed, please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are two places where you do `numOfItem - 1`; I would specify which is causing you confusion (or both if it's both).  Both are necessary for this code to not throw errors.  An array of size `X` has the indices `0, 1, ..., X-1`; attempting to access `stuff[numOfItem]` will result in an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code it trying to remove an element from an array if it is found using the following steps:

**Step 1** :

Find the element.

**Step 2** :

a) If not found, return false;

b) If found, shift all the elements to the left from the index where the element is found.

c) Set the last index of array as null.

In the **Step 2 b)** shift is done by:

```
for(int j = i; j < numOfItem - 1; j++) 
     stuff[j] = stuff[j + 1];
```

In this above code, you need to ***iterate for loop till second last index only***, because the **last index needs to be set as null** to **decrement the array size after deleting the element**. **If** you try to **iterate on last index**, then `stuff[j+1]` will **throw** `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException`. Thats why `numOfItem -1` works.

Comment: The part where i am getting confused is:lets say that the array size is 5 elements. So if i want to remove the last element, aka whatever is on i=4. Then the next part of the code will set j=i. Therefor j=4, but the 2nd condition is j < numOfItems -1. So if numOfItems is 5. 5-1=4. Therefore j must be less than 4?

Comment: That’s the required condition, because j should start from i and end till less than 4. If we allow to iterate for j=4, then stuff[j+1] will become stuff[5] which will throw ArrayOutOfIndexException, to avoid this check is necessary. So, j should be less than 4.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are referring to the line `stuff[numOfItem - 1] = null` If this is the case then the answer is simple. Array indexing starts at 0, not 1 therefore if you have 50 items in your array (numOfItem = 50) then the indexing will be 0, 1, 2, 3...49 There is not 50th value as index 0 is technically the 1st value in the array. Therefore if you wrote `stuff[numOfItem] = null` you would be trying to access the 50th index in the array however, the largest index in the array is 49 since it starts at 0, not 1.